# Ionic 4 upload screenshot to server

Tags: javascript, java, angular, mobile, ionic4

I want to take a screenshot and upload it to a server (I use `spring-boot`), for this I used native library screenshot and its angular service to get image URI, I transformed the image URI to a blob and I sent it using `FORMDATA` and post request of HTTPCLIENT, the problem is in back office where I got no parametre named file is found. Please, can anyone help me?

N.B: I use `MULTIPARTFILE` as `webservice` parametre type and `REQUESTPARAM` annotation.

here the java code :

```
    @PostMapping(value = { "/uploadImg/{idColis}" })
public void uploadScreenShot(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable String idColis) {
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            fileService.importerImage(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

angular code used :

```
  call(colis : any){
this.screenshot.URI(80).then(img => {
  this.screenShotsuccess = 'screened';
  this.colisService.upload(img,colis).subscribe(res=>{
    this.screenShotsuccess = 'screened and uploaded';
  });
}, err => {
  this.screenShotsuccess = err ;
} );}

upload(imgData : any,colis :any){

// Replace extension according to your media type
const imageName = colis.codeEnvoi+ '.jpg';
// call method that creates a blob from dataUri
const imageBlob = this.dataURItoBlob(imgData.URI);
const imageFile = new File([imageBlob], imageName, { type: 'image/jpeg' })

let  postData = new FormData();
postData.append('file', imageFile);

let data:Observable<any> = this.httpClient.post(this.wsListeUploadImage+colis.codeEnvoi,postData);
return data;}

  dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
console.log(dataURI);
const byteString = window.atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
  int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
 }
const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: 'image/jpeg' });    return blob;}
```

here is the error that i got :

```
2019-12-29 08:21:07.276  WARN 5356 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed. Could you please include the source code of your Spring Boot controller?

Comment: Hi Mafor i post it just now thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your Angular code, you are creating `FormData` correctly, but you never use it:

```
let data:Observable<any> = this.httpClient.post(this.wsListeUploadImage+colis.codeEnvoi,{'file':imageFile});
```

Change it to

```
let data:Observable<any> = this.httpClient.post(this.wsListeUploadImage+colis.codeEnvoi, postData);
```

Comment: i did it but always the same probleme